# How to split output of one @controller into two jsp files

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am learning Java and trying build a web application which stores data to mysql database and displays back the data in tables.

For the start I have gone through some online tutorials and written a small application which allows to add data dynamically to mysql tables and display all the fields of database table on the same page. To achieve this I have used @Controller. Below is the controller code and jsp page

```
package com.webappdemo01.controller;            

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.webappdemo01.model.Client;
import com.webappdemo01.service.ClientService;

@Controller
public class ClientController {
@Autowired
private ClientService clientService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
    Client client = new Client();
    map.put("client", client);
    map.put("clientList", clientService.getAllClient());
    return "client";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/client.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
    Client clientResult = new Client();
    switch(action.toLowerCase()){
    case "add":
        clientService.add(client);
        clientResult = client;
        break;
    case "edit":
        clientService.edit(client);
        clientResult = client;
        break;
    case "delete":
        clientService.delete(client.getClientname());
        clientResult = new Client();
        break;
    case "search":
        Client searchedClient = clientService.getClient(client.getClientname());
        clientResult = searchedClient!=null ? searchedClient : new Client();
        break;
    }
    map.put("client", clientResult);
    map.put("clientList", clientService.getAllClient());
    return "client";
  }

}
```

client.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/includes.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Client Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Client Data</h1>
<form:form action="client.do" method="POST" commandName="client">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Application Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="applicationname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Client Type</td>
            <td><form:input path="clienttype" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Client Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="clientname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hostname</td>
            <td><form:input path="hostname" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Environment</td>
            <td><form:input path="envtype" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Add" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <th>Application Name</th>
    <th>Client Type</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th>Hostname</th>
    <th>Environment</th>
    <c:forEach items="${clientList}" var="client">
        <tr>
            <td>${client.applicationname}</td>
            <td>${client.clienttype}</td>
            <td>${client.clientname}</td>
            <td>${client.hostname}</td>
            <td>${client.envtype}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

output is here

[image]

I want to slipt the output so that I can add the client in a page and display all the clients in different page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a separate method with its own mapping in your controller.

```
@RequestMapping("/clientForm")
public String clientForm(Map<String, Object> map){
    //do something
    //return data
}
```

You can use your `/index` to just show the list of clients. Then send request to `/clientForm` from your `client.jsp`. Similarly, put a `'clientForm.jsp` file within your `jsp` folder.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. Sorry for the late response it took some time for me to understanding. I am totally new to the java coding every word I come across in java is new for me

Comment: @GopiD no worries! I am glad, I could help. Just keep at it and you will be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

There are few basic issues with your code:

(1) You are trying to map all `HTTP` operations to POST, which is incorrect, rather use `GET` (query), `POST` (add), `DELETE` (delete), `PUT` (update) separately.

(2) You are trying to within a single controller method.

Rather the controller method with different operations needs to be split up as shown below:

```
@Controller
public class ClientController {

    @Autowired
    private ClientService clientService;

    @RequestMapping("/index", , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(Map<String, Object> map){
        Client client = new Client();
        map.put("client", client);
        map.put("clientList", clientService.getAllClient());
        return "client";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/client.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map){
        //code for clientService.add()
        return "clientResult";
    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/client.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doDelete(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map) {
        //code for clientService.delete()
        return "clientQueryResults";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/client.do", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String doActions(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map){
        //code for clientService.update()
        return "clientResult";
   }


    @RequestMapping(value="/client.do", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String doDelete(@ModelAttribute Client client, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> map) {
        //code for clientService.delete()
        return "clientResult";
    }
}
```

Also, ensure that you are passing the right `<form method="GET" ..>` or `<form method="DELETE" ..>` etc.. from your JSP page.